# Parametric sweep in OpenModelica using OMPython

Tags: python, modelica, openmodelica

I am trying to run a parametric sweep in OpenModelica using OMPython. Let's assume that I have a Modelica model *my_model.mo* belonging to the library *my_library*. The model has two parameters: *a* and *b*.
I successfully managed to run a single parametric run by using the following code:

```
from OMPython import OMCSessionZMQ
omc = OMCSessionZMQ()
omc.sendExpression('loadModel(my_library)')
omc.sendExpression('simulate(my_library.my_model, simflags="-overrideFile=parameter_sweep.txt", stopTime=86400)')
```

where the file parameter_sweep.txt is:

```
a=5
b=6
```

Now the question is: how can I run multiple parametric runs? I could add one more line to the code where a new txt file (parameter_sweep1.txt) with a new set of values for the parameters is used:

```
from OMPython import OMCSessionZMQ
omc = OMCSessionZMQ()
omc.sendExpression('loadModel(my_library)')
omc.sendExpression('simulate(my_library.my_model, simflags="-overrideFile=parameter_sweep.txt", stopTime=86400)')
omc.sendExpression('simulate(my_library.my_model, simflags="-overrideFile=parameter_sweep1.txt", stopTime=86400)')
```

However, I am afraid that in this way there is the need to recompile. Is there a way to do multiple parametric runs and avoid re-compilation?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `buildModel` command instead of `simulate` Then start the process manually in Python using a library such as `subprocess`. The command is simply something like:

```
["./my_library.my_model", "-overrideFile=parameter_sweep.txt"]
```

(If you use Windows, I believe you need to update your PATH environment variable as well, in order to find the used DLLs. If you use Linux, it just works.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is that I am trying to make a fully automated process that can be easily run also by other users. So I am not sure this approach would work for my case...

Comment: One solution could be to somehow adapt the code suggested here https://openmodelica.org/forum/default-topic/1670-how-to-perform-a-parameter-sweep, but I am not sure how to implement the for loop into the OMPython code (or generally how to run a .mos script via OMPython)

Comment: You can either run a whole mos-script using sendExpression. Or better: make the for-loops, etc in Python. By writing in Python, you have more control over what to do when there is an error. If everything is a big mos-script you don't really know if things succeeded inside a loop.